# Algorithm: Print the nth consecutive prime number

Tags: algorithm, primes

I'm currently learning algorithms and have came across a code challenge from an interviewer about a function that prints out the nth prime number sequentially. So it would be something like:

`getPrimeNth(10)` will print `1  2  3  5  7  11  13  17  19  23`

but most of the ones I found will print out just the nth number, so `23`, or just ones that will detect if it is prime numbers. I am going to risk getting downvoted for this but I can't seem to find the right solution for this.

Comment: Start by reading existing solutions. More likely than not, in the process of figuring out that 23 is the 9-th prime (1 is not a prime, by definition) they have figured out the other eight, and stored them in an array. All you need to do is printing that array now.

Answer (score 1):

One is not a prime, for starters.

Second, your question needs more clarification....

Primes are not challenging - there is a lot of information available.

The simplest solution for you would be to simply test every number by modding up to the square root of that number. If it mods to zero, it is not prime. Store the primes in an array one after another. I'm not going to straight up give you the answer, but read more about The Sieve of Eratosthenes - which is highly inefficient IMO, but where you must start.

Therefore, the first prime would be in slot 0, second in slot 1, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The below code tries to find and saves all possible primes upto N (defined by the macro). It just calls the utility function `is_prime()` which checks whether a given number is prime or not.

```
#define TRUE   1
#define FALSE  0
#define N 10

typedef short int bool;

bool is_prime(int num)
{
    int i = 2;

    for (i = 2; i <= (num - 1); i++) {
        if ((num % i) == 0) {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}


int main()
{
    int primes[N];
    int num_primes = 0;
    int num = 2; /* start with 2 */

    while (num_primes != N) {
        if (is_prime (num) == TRUE) {
            primes[num_primes] = num;
            num_primes++;
        }
        num++;
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf ("%d ", primes[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");

}
```

> Output: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29